# Injection of radiobuttonlist selected value into class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a webform with 4 types of phones like: LG, xiaomi, samsung and iphone. They will be in an Array and I will insert them into dynamic radiobuttonList in the page init.

Also, the user will have a textbox where he will put an amount of money he has. The user will also have a button that will calc if he have the budget for the selected phone from the list.

After the user selects the phone, write in the budget and press the button 
he will get "in budget" or "not enough budget".

The class have property of the array to insert the all the array from the page init and will have 2 functions:

One function will take the budget number > will go to the 2nd function that will see the selected phone and the budget > do its calcs and return the result into the 1st func that will give the feedback.

Now where I am stuck:

1. if the class isnt made global - and i put it in init or in button click - it wont work, so im looking for a way to make it work but without putting it global
2. so far i managed to inject the selected value into a class property and than compare - but i want to know if there is a way that this can happen with array inside class property
3. maybe if anyone can help me out and refer me to a guide where i can learn more about this subject (how inject selected value into function of a class and etc) ill be glad! as everything i see is C# with console but i work with ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION (.netframework)

   enter code here

   ```
   namespace gfjsr{
      public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page{
         phone InsertUserInfo = new phone();
   protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e){

       string[] myArr = new string[] { "samsung", "IPHONE", "XIAOMI","LG"};
       RadioButtonList phoneList = new RadioButtonList();
       phoneList.ID = "radioList";
       for (int i = 0; i< myArr.Length; i++)
       {
           ListItem li = new ListItem();
           li.Text = myArr[i];
           li.Value = i.ToString();
           phoneList.Items.Add(li);
       }


       Panel1.Controls.Add(phoneList);
       Label budgetLb = new Label();
       budgetLb.ID = "budglb";
       budgetLb.Text = "write your budget";
       Panel1.Controls.Add(budgetLb);

       TextBox insertBudg = new TextBox();
       insertBudg.ID = "budgTxt";
       Panel1.Controls.Add(insertBudg);

       Button myBtn = new Button(); 
       myBtn.ID = "btn1"; 
       myBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_click);
       myBtn.Text = "result";
       Panel1.Controls.Add(myBtn);

       Label Labelfeedback = new Label();
       Labelfeedback.ID = "feedback";
       Labelfeedback.Text = "";
       Panel1.Controls.Add(Labelfeedback);

   }
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }
   protected void btn1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       InsertUserInfo.phoneChosen = ((RadioButtonList)FindControl("radioList")).SelectedItem.Text;
       double UserBudget = 
       Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)FindControl("budgTxt")).Text);
       InsertUserInfo.BudgetYN(UserBudget);
       ((Label)FindControl("feedback")).Text = InsertUserInfo.feedback; }}}


   namespace gfjsr{
   public class phone{
   private string _phoneChosen;

   public string phoneChosen
   {
       get { return _phoneChosen; }
       set { _phoneChosen = value; }
   }


   private string _feedback;

   public string feedback
   {
       get { return _feedback; }
       set { _feedback = value; }
   }

   public double Func1(string x)
   {
       double phonePrice = 0;

       if( x == "samsung")
       {
        phonePrice = 4000;

       }
       if (x == "IPHONE")
       {
        phonePrice = 3500;

       }
       if (x == "XIAOMI")
       {
        phonePrice = 3000;

       }
       if (x == "LG")
       {
        phonePrice = 2000;

       }
       return phonePrice;
   }

   public void BudgetYN(double y)
   {
       if(y >= Func1(_phoneChosen))
       {
           _feedback = "positive";
       }
       else
       {
           _feedback = "no";
       }
    }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you trying to replace string[] myArr = new string[] { "samsung", "IPHONE", "XIAOMI","LG"}; with an injected array?

Comment: In trying to find a way not to use this array as global, but to put it somehow as class property and still make it so the function will recognize what person chose from the radio button list

Comment: I would have a separate method that retrieves the values from somewhere, probably a database and call that on init to populate the list. That way the code will be dynamic based on the list supplied and it won't be hardcoded. Is that the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: no option without extra methods?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to have the flexibility of changing the values without redeploying the code, then you could always use an enum.